# What is 'metal mask' here?

Tags: pcb

It's common to see 'solder mask' in PCB design. But sometimes, I see 'metal mask', such as in page 5 of [this datasheet](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=FX11&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D31694_en), does it mean I need to design a pad larger than the solder mask opening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metal mask in this case I believe refers to the solder paste stencil, given it specifies a thickness.

Comment: And solder paste stencils are usually made of metal, except for the very cheapest (you can get mylar ones for one-off designs, but they can't usually be used more than a handful of times). I'd personally call it something more like "paste mask" or "stencil layer" for clarity, though.